# How Do I automatically update TexT? Android Studio?

Tags: android, textview, refresh

I am parsing a JSON response and when I click a button it updates the text but only on refresh, how do I get it to instantly, and dynamically update the texT??

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_ANSWER, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                listblogs = parseJSONResponseQuestion(response);
                mAdapterQuestion.setBloglist(listblogs);
                System.out.println(response);
                System.out.println("it worked!!!");
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(error);

            }
        });
        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }


    private ArrayList<Blogs> parseJSONResponseQuestion(JSONArray response) {
        if (!response.equals("")) {
            ArrayList<Blogs> blogsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(i);
            String text = currentQuestions.getString("text");
            String questionId = currentQuestions.getString("questionId");
            String votes = currentQuestions.getString("votes");
            String Answerid = currentQuestions.getString("id");
            String selectedId = currentQuestions.getString("selected");
            System.out.println(response.length() + "length");

            data.append(text + Answerid + "\n");

            System.out.println(data);
            Blogs blogs = new Blogs();
            blogs.setMtext(text);
            blogs.setVotes(votes);
            blogs.setId(Answerid);
            blogs.setSelected(selectedId);
            System.out.print(Answerid);
            listblogs.add(blogs);
        }
        System.out.println(data.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

return listblogs;
}
```

The only thing I have tried it recalling the jsonarray in my listener

```
public void OnDown(View view) {
CharSequence IdDownVote = ((TextView) ((RelativeLayout) view.getParent()).getChildAt(1)).getText();
final RequestQueue mrequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
final String PUT_VOTE_DOWN = "someURL";

StringRequest PostVoteUp = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, PUT_VOTE_DOWN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        System.out.println(response + "reponse");

    }

}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("************Answer" + error + "error");
    }
});
mrequestQueue.add(PostVoteUp);

System.out.println("VOTED DOWN");
```

}

Comment: you have to create a `Service` that will check that `JSON` response and every specific time you will run a `Thread` that will update it for you

Comment: Hey, I dont know i a service is the best option in this case I gave you a little more details to work off of do you still think a service is the best option?

Comment: You want something to check the response every specific time and update the text is that correct?

Comment: I want the text to be instantly updated every single time I press a button, currently if I press a button I would need to refresh the entire page I dont want to do that.

Comment: show me the clicklistener for the update button and which method you call

Comment: the clicklistener is public void OnDown(View view) { and I am passing in CharSequence IdDownVote = ((TextView) ((RelativeLayout) view.getParent()).getChildAt(1)).getText(); which is the             String Answerid = currentQuestions.getString("id"); in my JsonArrayRequest request

Comment: and then I pass the value of answerId into some Url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102021/discussion-between-eli-and-helldawg13).